# Render widgets based on AppLifeCycleState, Hide the page when viewing list of running apps

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following code which will replace the child with a container when the app goes to inactive or paused state.

This is not working in IOS and also inconsistent in Android

```
class SecureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
final Widget child;
SecureScreen({@required this.child});

@override
 SecureScreenState createState() => SecureScreenState();
}

class SecureScreenState extends State<SecureScreen>
with WidgetsBindingObserver {
AppLifecycleState _notification;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
}

@override
void dispose() {
WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
super.dispose();
}

@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
print(state.toString());
setState(() {
  _notification = state;
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return (_notification == AppLifecycleState.paused ||
        _notification == AppLifecycleState.inactive)
    ? Container(
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
      )
    : widget.child; 
  }


}
```

Is this the best way to approach the problem, if yes what do I have to change in order to get this work. If not please suggest an alternative solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `This is not working in iOS and also inconsistent in Android`. What problem are you facing? This is supposed to work. Perhaps you should consider opening an issue at Flutter's repo. `Is this the best way to approach the problem`. No, it's the **only** way.

Comment: I have opened an issue in Flutter's repo. here is the link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33236. I have attached a screenshot and the entire code that I used. When I double press the home button in IOS, it is sending in the "inactive" state but it is not calling build() method to render based on the condition.thanks